# "Поэтому первое (?) надо сделать интервью..." — какой знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

**Поэтому первое (?) надо сделать интервью с дикторами ТД.**
(ТД — тотальный диктант.)

Comment: Если срочно... «Первое, что надо сделать, —  интервью.»

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ

Comment: Если нет союза"что",ставится двоеточие.

Answer (score 1):

Можно оставить тире, можно нарисовать двоеточие - факультативно и на усмотрение автора.

Comment: Спасибо. А можете объяснить, почему именно эти знаки (просто я еще насчет запятой думала)? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Запятая должна что-то от чего-то отделять, не пройдёт. Сгодилась бы точка, если б было второе и третье. А тире и двоеточие в этом случае взаимозаменяемы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!!

Comment: Я тоже за тире, если нельзя изменить фразу. В данном случае получается некий нумерованный список (перечисление) "Первое", "Второе" : "Поэтому первое - надо сделать ... Второе - ..." Примеры из Нацкорпуса : http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%EE%FD%F2%EE%EC%F3+%EF%E5%F0%E2%EE%E5